# 1-to-4 broadcast and 4-to-1 reduce in AVX-512

Tags: sse, avx512

I need to do the following two operations:

```
float x[4];
float y[16];

// 1-to-4 broadcast
for ( int i = 0; i < 16; ++i )
    y[i] = x[i / 4];

// 4-to-1 reduce-add
for ( int i = 0; i < 16; ++i )
    x[i / 4] += y[i];
```

What would be an efficient AVX-512 implementation?

Comment: Are you tuning for KNL (Xeon Phi), or for Skylake-AVX512?  There might be a difference.  Is this done inside a loop, or repeatedly?  (i.e. can you keep a a shuffle-control vector in a register for a 128->512 broadcast + an in-lane shuffle with `vpermilps zmm`?  (To broadcast a different element within each 128-bit lane).

Comment: Skylake. Yes, I have a set of vectors `x[n*4]` and `y[n*16]` and a loop over size 4 and 16 respecrively subvectors of `x` and `y`, so I can have shuffle control in a register

Comment: Ok good, then the extra stuff about `vpermt2ps` to combine two vectors with per-lane horizontal sums in my answer applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reduce-add, just do in-lane shuffles and adds (`vmovshdup` / `vaddps` / `vpermilps imm8`/`vaddps`) like in [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86/35270026#35270026) to get a horizontal sum in each 128-bit lane, and then [`vpermps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMPS.html) to shuffle the desired elements to the bottom.  Or [`vcompressps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VCOMPRESSPS.html) with a constant mask to do the same thing, optionally with a memory destination.

Once packed down to a single vector, you have a normal SIMD 128-bit add.

If your arrays are actually larger than 16, instead of `vpermps` you could [`vpermt2ps`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMT2W:VPERMT2D:VPERMT2Q:VPERMT2PS:VPERMT2PD.html) to take every 4th element from each of two source vectors, setting you up for doing the `+=` part with into `x[]` 256-bit vectors.  (Or combine again with another shuffle into 512-bit vectors, but that will probably bottleneck on shuffle throughput on SKX).

On SKX, `vpermt2ps` is only a single uop, with 1c throughput / 3c latency, so it's very efficient for how powerful it is.  On KNL it has 2c throughput, worse than `vpermps`, but maybe still worth it.  (KNL doesn't have AVX512VL, but for adding to `x[]` with 256-bit vectors you (or a compiler) can use AVX1 `vaddps ymm` if you want.)

See https://agner.org/optimize/ for instruction tables.

---

For the load:

Is this done inside a loop, or repeatedly?  (i.e. can you keep a a shuffle-control vector in a register?  If so, you could

- do a 128->512 broadcast with [`VBROADCASTF32X4`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VBROADCAST.html) (single uop for a load port).
- do an in-lane shuffle with [`vpermilps zmm,zmm,zmm`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMILPS.html) to broadcast a different element within each 128-bit lane.  (Has to be separate from the broadcast-load, because a memory-source `vpermilps` can either have a `m512` or `m32bcst` source.  (Instructions typically have their memory broadcast granularity = their element size, unfortunately in some cases like this where it's not at all useful.  And `vpermilps` takes the control vector as a memory operand, not the source data.)

This is *slightly* better than `vpermps zmm,zmm,zmm` because the shuffle has 1 cycle latency instead of 3 (on Skylake-avx512).

Even outside a loop, loading a shuffle-control vector might still be your best bet.